# onClick event - change data for a single row in react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have a column in my react table that is using a variable (named item) for displaying its data. As shown in the code below:

```
{
  Header: this.generateHeaderCell(this.props.headers[3]),
  accessor: 'last_updated_status',
  Cell: (props: any) => <DateSinceFormat date={props.value} item={item}/>,
  maxWidth: 85,
  filterable: false
}
```

So when the value of variable **item** is 1 it displays some data and when it's changed it displays something else.

I am using the onClick event for changing the value of **item**.

```
onRowClick = (state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
    return {
        onClick: e => {
            if(item === '2') {
                item = '1';
            } else {
                item = '2';
            }
            instance.forceUpdate();
        }
    };
}
```

**The problem I face here is, I only want to update the value for a particular row, that is clicked by the user, however, right now all the rows are getting updated.**

Please help me out here and let me know how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like value for `item` is being shared between all rows. You can try to add `item` property to `rowInfo` (I assume it's an object), and change `onClick()` function to

```
onClick: e => {
         if(rowInfo.item === '2') 
         {
             rowInfo.item = '1';
         } 
         else 
         {
             rowInfo.item = '2';
         }
   instance.forceUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however as in the code below I am using the item variable in this way =>


**Cell: (props: any) => <DateSinceFormat date={props.value} item={item}/>**

How can I use rowInfo.item over here?

Comment: I see! Is there any way you could share the component code, so I see what are the scopes for the table elements and when the function is being called?